# Make customView scrollable when drew line became more than View size

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am  using a custom View and plotting line of double  size of Custom View

Following is   my Custom View in xml

```
     <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="780dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_x="20dp"
    android:layout_y="180dp">     
 <com.john.TestApp.ScrollLineView
    android:id="@+id/RectroGraphView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >
  </com.john.TestApp.ScrollLineView> </HorizontalScrollView>
```

And this is  my ScrollLineView  view class code. As you  can see my line is  more than double size of custom view. but when I am running it is not even plotting any line.

I want whenever my line  goes  out of size, custom view has to be scrollable.

```
  public ScrollLineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);

    pTestPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    setWillNotDraw(false);

} 

@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas StoredPlotCanvas) 
{ 
     super.onDraw(StoredPlotCanvas);

     StoredPlotCanvas.drawLine(0, 150, 2500, 150, pTestPaint); 
     StoredPlotCanvas.drawLine(0, 200, 1000, 200, pTestPaint); 
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way, but you would need to override and implement custom `onMeasure` method in your ScrollLineView class. Then whenever you draw the line you would need to call `requestLayout()` and adjust view size in `onMeasure` method, so it can be scrolled.

In my opinion it would be much better solution to implement custom scrolling in ScrollLineView. You would just need to adjust offsets of what you are currently drawing.

Comment: Thanks for Reply ...Do you have any  code samples?  please I amnew  in android can you give me sample  code?